# Retrieve last record of SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

Here is the my problem: I have a SQL Server database called `emp`. It has an `employee` table (with `userid int` column). I need to retrieve the last record of the `userid` in `employee` table with increment userid value + 1. At the moment I did it on the my GUI. So how do I write a sql query for it?

Answer (score 3):

To return the the record with the highest userid, you can do:

```
SELECT TOP 1 userid
FROM employee
ORDER BY userid DESC
```

or...

```
SELECT MAX(userid)
FROM employee
```

If your plan is to then increment the userid manually and insert a new record with that new ID, I'd recommend against doing that - what if 2 processes try to do it at the same time? Instead, use an IDENTITY column as userid and let the incrementing be handled for you automatically

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be manually incrementing the userid column, use an IDENTITY column instead.  That will automatically add 1 for you for every new row.

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
    UserId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    UserName NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    // etc add other columns here
)
```

If you really really have to select the highest userid it is a very simple query:

```
SELECT MAX(UserId) + 1
FROM Employees
```

[Edit]

Based on your comments, you should use the `SELECT MAX(UserId) + 1 FROM Employees` query.  But be aware that this does not guarantee the number will be the ID.  Normally you would not show an Id value until after the record has been saved to the database.

Comment: thank you for your quick rely JK.but the my requiremnt is this.my gui have a form called new emloyee.so there is a text feild it shows user id from emp table.when click add new employee i want to display that test val as last value of emp id +1.

Comment: If you need to show what the Id of the new employee will be before you've actually added the employee then use the query above: `SELECT MAX(UserId) + 1 FROM Employees`.  But there is a chance that that will not be the Id number when the new employee is actually saved.

Answer (score -1):

This will give you last inserted record, If you don't have Identity column.

```
EXECUTE ('DECLARE GETLAST CURSOR DYNAMIC FOR SELECT * FROM [User]')
OPEN GETLAST
FETCH LAST FROM GETLAST
CLOSE GETLAST
DEALLOCATE GETLAST
```

If you have set identity than you can use following.

```
SELECT top(1) ID from [YourTable] order by ID desc
```

Comment: There's **really** no need for a cursor (big big performance killer!!) in this situation.....

Comment: This will get you last inserted record if you don't have any ID as autoincrement. Try Replacing table and and see result

Comment: Yeah, I think marc s is a bit harch!  - Cursors are a performance killer for row by row operations, but in this case it only gets the last record

Answer (score -1):

To have the new userid before saving, create a NextId table.

Before inserting the user, get the new value from NextId:

```
UserId = SELECT Coalesce(NextId, 0) + 1 from NextId
```

Then update the  NextID table:

```
UPDATE NEXTID SET NextId = IserID
```

And then use that value in your user creation code

You can get gaps, there are more complicated methods to avoid them; but I think this will do

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Is that the reason for the minus 1?